# Regular Expression Oracle SQL : handling multiple cases

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am using Regex Substring to filter out values that have 'p' in the start and ends before '-'. p is followed by 6 digits.

My Code  :

```
 code,REGEXP_SUBSTR(CODE,'^[p][^-]+')
```

| `CODE` | `REGEXP_SUBSTR(CODE,'^[P][^-]+')` |
| --- | --- |
| p700401- | p700401 |
| p791701- | p791701 |
| 100-,p788001-, | null |

This is the result , but I  am struggling to handle cases like in 3rd Row.

`100-,p788001-`

Can Someone Please guide me to handle such cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match complete terms in a comma-delimited string then you can use:

```sql
SELECT code,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(code, '(^|,)(p\d{6})-(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) AS result
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (code) as
  SELECT 'p700401-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'p791701-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '100-,p788001-,' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '123-,p456789-xyz,p987654-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'p111111-,p222222-not_this,p333333-,p444444-' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CODE | RESULT |
| --- | --- |
| p700401- | p700401 |
| p791701- | p791701 |
| 100-,p788001-, | p788001 |
| 123-,p456789-xyz,p987654- | p987654 |
| p111111-,p222222-not_this,p333333-,p444444- | p111111 |

---

#### Displaying multiple terms

If you want to remove the non-matching terms from the string then:

```
SELECT code,
       LTRIM(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           ',' || REPLACE(code, ',', ',,') || ',',
           '((,p\d{6})-,)|,.*?,',
           '\2'
         ),
         ','
       ) AS result
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, outputs:

| CODE | RESULT |
| --- | --- |
| p700401- | p700401 |
| p791701- | p791701 |
| 100-,p788001-, | p788001 |
| 123-,p456789-xyz,p987654- | p987654 |
| p111111-,p222222-not_this,p333333-,p444444- | p111111,p333333,p444444 |

And if you want to split the list into rows then:

```
SELECT t.code,
       i.*
FROM   (
         SELECT code,
                ',' || REPLACE(code, ',', ',,') || ',' AS double_delims
         FROM   table_name
       ) t
       INNER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEVEL As item,
                REGEXP_SUBSTR(double_delims, ',(p\d{6})-,|,(.*?),', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1)
                  AS value
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(double_delims, ',(p\d{6})-,|,(.*?),')
       ) i
       ON (i.value IS NOT NULL);
```

Which outputs:

| CODE | ITEM | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p700401- | 1 | p700401 |
| p791701- | 1 | p791701 |
| 100-,p788001-, | 2 | p788001 |
| 123-,p456789-xyz,p987654- | 3 | p987654 |
| p111111-,p222222-not_this,p333333-,p444444- | 1 | p111111 |
| p111111-,p222222-not_this,p333333-,p444444- | 3 | p333333 |
| p111111-,p222222-not_this,p333333-,p444444- | 4 | p444444 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cWOX3AOY)

Comment: + But did you leave out the first number out of the results on purpose in line 4?

Comment: @JvdV The first line states "If you want to match complete terms" and the regular expression would not match the complete term for `,p456789-xyz,`; so, yes, that row was included to show that it would match the correct term when matching complete terms and it should match the last term in the delimited list and not the middle term.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear how you interpreted the data then. I borrowed how you created the schema but could have misinterpreted the desired outcome then.

Comment: thanks MT0 for the thorough answer. Always appreciate the input .

Answer (score 1):

For sample data you posted, this returns the result you wanted (i.e. take "p" followed by exactly 6 digits):

```
SQL> with test (code) as
  2    (select 'p700401-' from dual union all
  3     select 'p791701-' from dual union all
  4     select '100-,p788001-,' from dual
  5    )
  6  select code,
  7         regexp_substr(code, 'p\d{6}') result
  8  from test;

CODE           RESULT
-------------- --------------
p700401-       p700401
p791701-       p791701
100-,p788001-, p788001

SQL>
```

Comment: Can I ask you a question @Littlefoot? Would something like `SELECT code, REGEXP_REPLACE (code, '(?:\b[^p,-]\w*-,|,$)', '') result FROM test;` work? I was thinking what if data is something like `100-,p788001-,100-,p788002-`, but I have no means of testing this.

Comment: It wouldn't work, @JvdV, I tested it. That regex returns the "original" code, doesn't "replace" anything.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wonder why. Maybe part of the regex would not be supported syntax. The idea would be to return something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/YXa2SO/1). Maybe the non-capturing group is supposed to be a [regular capture group](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php)...

Comment: I'm not that good at regex, @JvdV; I only know *some* Oracle syntax. Wiktor Stribiżew is the regex expert here, I guess he'd be able to explain it.

Comment: @JvdV Oracle does not support non-capturing groups `(: )` or word boundaries `\b` so you cannot use that method.

Comment: @MT0, yeah I just figured out the lack of support for word-boundaries. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Right, my two cents is to use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php):

```
CREATE TABLE tst (code) as
  SELECT 'p700401-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'p791701-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '100-,z123456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '100-,p788001-,' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'p788001-,100-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '123-,p456789-xyz,p987654-' FROM DUAL;

SELECT
  code, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(code, '(p\d{6})-|.', '\1'), '(\d)(p)', '\1,\2') AS result
FROM tst
```

Resuls in:

| CODE | RESULT |
| --- | --- |
| p700401- | p700401 |
| p791701- | p791701 |
| 100-,z123456 | null |
| 100-,p788001-, | p788001 |
| p788001-,100- | p788001 |
| 123-,p456789-xyz,p987654- | p456789,p987654 |

It's a nested statement due to the lack of support for handy regex syntax as per given link.

The 1st regex pattern is supposed to replace anything other than what you are after, see an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/T9crba/1). The 2nd one is there to insert comma's back to seperate these values, see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/P0COKB/1).